# Was this a bad question?

Tags: discussion, bad-questions

I recently posted [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743328/why-is-microsoft-net-framework-4-6-1-offline-installer-suddenly-gone).  See [the first version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38743328/revisions) as I added stuff later when I realised my mistake.

**Prior to the question:**
I was about to install something on a production server.  The updated software needed the 4.6.1 version of the .Net framework.  I therefore did as I have done many times before, just google for an offline version of the installer.  Surprisingly I instead reached a page with the message I posted in the question.  So I tried other links, but no matter where I went to download the file I got the same message.

**My thinking:** I admit to not thinking of trying another browser or another machine, but instead tried to google if someone else had asked the question previously.  I could not find such a question.  Since I had downloaded the file just a few days earlier I checked my download folder quickly, but I could not spot it.  Besides, I got the feeling that maybe it wasn't such a good idea to install something in case it had just been withdrawn by Microsoft.  Why I got this thought is hard to say.

**Was this a bad question?** How should I have written my question to ask about this?  I was stuck.  Maybe I had eaten too much chocolate.  But I tried to write a decent question, checked my spelling and explained my thinking.  But then I was downvoted very quickly, but mostly without an accompanying explanation. Why is this a bad question for Stack Overflow?  I mean, I could have provided the links, but I thought adding links that I thought was broken already was no point.  I could have provided a screen shot to give proof that this was not just bad googling om my side.

I read through [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67960/what-is-a-bad-question), but could find no really obvious reason it was such a bad question.

Any thoughts/opinions?

Answer (score 4):

Installation questions or questions regarding products not directly related to programming (e.g. vim configuration), especially on where to find them or why they have disappeared, are just considered off-topic.

Stack Overflow tries to concern itself primarily with how to accomplish some task in code, and tends to be quite strict about this.

Your question's headline, "Why is Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6.1 offline installer suddenly gone?" is simply off-topic. Asking where an offline installer is not directly a programming question -- it is a programming *tool installation* question. For just this reason, it is considered off-topic.

Comment: Installation questions are not necessarily off-topic. They may fall under "tools used by developers". Questions asking where to find tools, or why they are gone, are indeed off-topic.

Comment: @S.L.Barth I could go as far to say that installation questions can be off-topic for the same reason why a question asking for installation instructions for a compiler can be off-topic.

Comment: Just curious, is there a stack-site for questions like this?  I use StackOverflow as my first go to for all programming related questions.

Comment: @Halvard Typically, sites like Super User might be appropriate. However, to  my knowledge, there really no good place to ask questions like this except for the original vendor, but even then, you might encounter HR instead of the technical expertise you need to talk with. **Stack Overflow is not for all programming-related questions; I'd say it's for programming-specific questions.**

Comment: @VermillionAzure I don't even think I would try to find out where to ask Microsoft about this.  I guess I took the down votes as saying the question was poorly asked, not that it was off-topic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

At first glance, the question seems to ask why an offline resource is gone. The answer to *why is X gone* can only reliably answered by the party that provides the resource - in this case, Microsoft.

As it turned out, it was an issue on your side. So it wasn't Microsoft policies at all.

Unfortunately, I don't think this question could have been salvaged by phrasing it differently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I guess I was stressed by the situation and thought that if something as important as 4.6.1 had been withdrawn without an explanation on the download site something was seriously wrong and to the interest of a lot of programmers on StackOverflow.  But I was of course just experiencing my own delusions :)

Comment: You're welcome. Most people are under stress when they ask a question on SO. I'm glad that you were able to resolve the issue. BTW, sometimes this type of question is allowed in chat. It depends on the rules of the individual chatroom.